# How can I code my game to work on every resolution of Android devices? (with Unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

I have a game what I made in 480x320 resolution (I have set it in the build settings) in Unity. But I would like to publish my game for every Android device with every resolution. How can I do it, to tell Unity to scale my game up to the device's resolution? Is it possible to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16):

The answer to your question largely depends on how you've implemented the game. If you've created it using GUI textures, then it largely depends on how you've placed/sized your objects versus screen size, which makes things a little tricky.

If the majority of your game is done using objects (such as planes, cubes, etc) then there's two methods I usually choose to use.

1) First method is very easy to implement, though doesn't always look too good. You can simply change the camera's aspect ratio to match the one you've designed your game around. So in your case, since you've designed your game at 4:3, you'd do something like this:

```
Camera.aspect = 4f/3f;
```

However, if someone's playing on a screen meant for 16:9, the game will end up looking distorted and stretched.

2) The second method isn't as easy, requiring quite a bit of work and calculations, but will give a much cleaner looking result for you. If you're using an orthographic camera, one important thing to keep in mind is that regardless of what screen resolution is being used, the orthographic camera keeps the height at a set height and only changes the width. For example, with an orthographic camera at a size of 10, the height will be set to 2. With this in mind what you'd need to do is compensate for the widest possible camera within each level (for example, have a wide background) or dynamically change the Orthographic Size of the camera until its width matches what you've created.

If you've done a 3d game with a stereoscopic camera , screen resolution shouldn't really affect how it looks, but I guess that depends on the game, so more info would be required

Comment: I make a game using objects (cubes, spheres). This game is a 2D game made in Unity 3D world.

Comment: if it's 2D then you must be using the orthographic camera, so just follow the tips I gave for that.

Answer (score 9):

The way i did is to change camera viewport according to device aspect ratio
Consider you made the game for 800x1280

The you can do this in any one of the script

```
float xFactor = Screen.width / 800f;
float yFactor = Screen.height  / 1280f;


Camera.main.rect=new Rect(0,0,1,xFactor/yFactor);
```

and this works like magic

Comment: Guys this is kinda buggy, ill recommend using @Nelson Austria's answer,

Answer (score 2):

A easy way to do this is considering your target, I mean  if you're doing a game for Iphone 5 then the aspect ratio is 9:16 v or 16:9 h.

```
   public float targetRatio = 9f/16f; //The aspect ratio you did for the game.
void Start()
{
   Camera cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
   cam.aspect = targetRatio;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my script for scaling the ortographic camera in 2D games

```
public float screenHeight = 1920f;
public float screenWidth = 1080f;
public float targetAspect = 9f / 16f;
public float orthographicSize;
private Camera mainCamera;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    // Initialize variables
    mainCamera = Camera.main;
    orthographicSize = mainCamera.orthographicSize;

    // Calculating ortographic width
    float orthoWidth = orthographicSize / screenHeight * screenWidth;
    // Setting aspect ration
    orthoWidth = orthoWidth / (targetAspect / mainCamera.aspect);
    // Setting Size
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = (orthoWidth / Screen.width * Screen.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's 2D instead of 3D, this what I [do](https://kokizzu.blogspot.com/2019/04/how-to-make-2d-game-that-fit-multiple.html):

1. Create a Canvas object
2. Set the Canvas Scaler to Scale with Screen Size
3. Set the Reference Resolution to for example: 480x320
4. Set the Screen Match Mode to *match width or height*
5. Set the match to 1 if your current screen width is smaller (0 if height is smaller)
6. Create an Image as background inside the Canvas
7. Add Aspect Ratio Fitter script
8. Set the Aspect Mode to Fit in Parent (so the UI anchor can be anywhere)
9. Set the Aspect Ratio to 480/320 = 1.5

And add this snippet on main Canvas' Awake method:

```
var canvasScaler = GetComponent<CanvasScaler>();
var ratio = Screen.height / (float) Screen.width;
var rr = canvasScaler.referenceResolution;
canvasScaler.matchWidthOrHeight = (ratio < rr.x / rr.y) ? 1 : 0;
//Make sure to add Using Unity.UI on top of your Aspect Ratio Script!
```

For 3D objects you can use any of the answers above

Comment: Hey Kokizzu, I was wondering if this is applicable at any point in game development? For example, I have everything ready to production, but something I forgot to consider is the fact that I want to make it work for different devices. So I was wondering there is a way to salvage the game? So far, my canvas is being used for just my score system and tutorial instructions. Everything else is outside of my canvas.

Comment: not sure, need to test, but I haven't touch unity again for 3 years.
if you don't care about aspect ratio, then you can just anchor your controls/buttons to corners or sides so it would always fit most of the common resolutions (except for smaller ones).

Comment: So I was testing it when I commented. However, it moves everything (I think it has to do with anchors like you mentioned). I will try to add anchors to the corners instead of the center of my canvas. Thanks for the response haha, and welcome back to this old comment lol

Answer (score -1):

The best solution for me is to use the theorem of intersecting lines so that there is neither a cut-off on the sides nor a distortion of the game view. That means that you have to step back or forward depending on the different aspect ratio.

If you like, I have [an asset on the Unity asset store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/27922) which automatically corrects the camera distance so you never have a distortion or a cut off no matter which handheld device you are using.