# Why Rigidbody2D velocity have different result in differerent resolution ?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using this comamnd in unity to move an object(an UI Button) :

```
Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(x,x);
```

Can anyone tell me why i have different result in different device(resolution)?

```
x = Screen.Width/2;
```

Comment: Well, because Screen.Width returns result in pixels. And different devices have different resolutions in pixels.

Comment: Ok but if you see i wrote "x = Screen.Width/2;"
it means in every resolutions i have a move from 0 to width/2 . isn't it?

Comment: Nope. the object will move in 3d world space. Very much different from your screen resolution. But if you want to stick with middle of screen to move, use screentoworldpoint instead of rigidbody forcing.

Comment: main goal is to have a jump from left to right .but the jump should be the same in all devices and all resolutions.is it good idea to use screentoworldpoint  yet?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862677/how-can-i-code-my-game-to-work-on-every-resolution-of-android-devices-with-uni and http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-move-GameObjects-using-the-same-code-when-there-are-different-resolutions-Unity might help